# CodeMirror document.getElementById on all id's with x before hyphen

Tags: javascript, jquery, codemirror

I have a few textareas on the page where i am running CodeMirror to do some syntax highlighting and enable editing of code.

Currently i select one textarea via: `CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code")` but my text areas are numerical and start from 1 so my id's are as follows:

```
code-1
code-2
```

How would i use something like `div[id|='code']` which i believe will look at everything before the hyphen? I assume i'd need something different from `getElementById` for this?

Comment: You'd probably be better off giving the elements a class in addition to the id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use jQuery's 'attribute begins with' selector for this:

```
$('textarea[id^=code-]').each(function() {
    CodeMirror.fromTextArea(this);
});
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! A little cheeky extra, how could i pass some options into this? I keep getting syntax wrong i think.

Comment: What options do you need to pass? I'm not familiar with CodeMirror.